# Updating jsp variable inside of javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a variable defined at the top of my jsp page:

```
<%! int count = 0; %>
```

I then call jquery with a buttonclick like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {         
    $('#somebutton').click(function() {
        var c = '<%=count%>';
        <% count += 5; %>
    });
});
</script>
```

The idea is that the variable count will be updated (and persist) after the function is done.  However, it seems to update count locally but doesn't persist globally.  When I click the button count always gets set to 5 but never increments to 10, 15, etc. upon further button clicks.

How can I update the jsp variable from within the jquery function and have it persist?

Comment: JSP is server-side. JavaScript is client-side. The two don't mix; what you're doing is incrementing it once.

Comment: JSP produces HTML which get sent from webserver to webbrowser. JS is part of HTML. Rightclick page in browser and *View Source* to get enlightenend.

Comment: BalusC, I'm aware that pages are made up of HTML.  Thanks, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to do a call back to the server and store the data in a session variable (or cookie I suppose depending on the security needs).

Comment: For what I'm doing a cookie might suffice.  Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

@Aaron-You can use one method in javascript like

```
function increment(){
                var value1=document.getElementById("lbl1").value;
                value1=parseInt(value1)+5;
                document.getElementById("lbl1").innerText=value1;
            }
```

where lbl1 is the id of the textbox in your jsp which has the initialized value as 0 i.e. `<input type="text" value="<%=count%>" id="lbl1"/>`. and on button click call increment() method like this `<input type="submit" onclick="increment()"/>.`

Hope this meets your requirements...

Comment: Nice idea, I ended up using a cookie but this is an interesting trick and would have probably also worked.

Comment: offcourse you can do with cookies also, but for this small requirement cookies methodology will be too lengthy...